# Using a Registered Function in Nhibernate ICriteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, full-text-search, icriteria, freetext

I have som trouble using fulltext search in NHibernate ICriteria

I have registered freetext and contains as below:

```
public class CMSSQLDialect : MsSql2008Dialect   {
    public CMSSQLDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("freetext", new StandardSQLFunction("freetext", null));
        RegisterFunction("contains", new StandardSQLFunction("contains", null));
    }
}
```

Now i want to use the functions in an ICriteria like:

```
var store = sessionFactory.CreateCriteria(typeof(Comito.CMS.Domain.Entity.Document.Document));
var stringSearchProjection = Projections.SqlFunction("freetext", NHibernateUtil.StringClob, Projections.Property("BodyText"));
```

Trying to add the projection to the search:

```
store.Add(Restrictions.Eq(stringSearchProjection , '*mysearch*'));
```

(of course) returns

```
SELECT  this_.BodyText as y0_ FROM TableName WHERE  freetext(this_.BodyText) = 'dav'
```

But how do I then implement the freetext in ICriteria

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we do **not** need to register SQL function for projections. We can just use it in the WHERE clause like that:

```
store.Add(
    Expression.Sql(
        "CONTAINS(BodyText, ?)",
        "*mysearch*",
        NHibernateUtil.String
    )
);
```

*The `Expression` is `NHibernate.Criterion.Expression`*